# How to add button column picker visibility to ridzen grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor server side . I need to add button column picker visibility

so by click button if I select column application id and application name then 2 columns only will display and another columns will hide

what I do as below

@code

```
 private IEnumerable<ApplicationValuesDto> AllApplicationsList = Array.Empty<ApplicationValuesDto>();



public class ApplicationValuesDto
    {
        public int applicationId { get; set; }
        public string applicationName { get; set; }
        public string commonName { get; set; }
        public string typeOfApplication { get; set; }

    }
```

I fill radzen grid by

```
private async Task SearchFilter()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, config["API_URL"] + "Application/SearchFullDataLike/" + appfilter.server_Name + "/" + appfilter.databaseName + "/" + appfilter.ownerName);
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        AllApplicationsList = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<ApplicationValuesDto>>(responsestream);

    }
```

I load data on

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    await SearchFilter();
         
    }

 <RadzenGrid AllowPaging="true" PageSize=@pageSize chan AllowFiltering="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" AllowSorting="true"
                                                data="@AllApplicationsList"
                                                IsLoading="@isLoading"
                                                TItem="ApplicationValuesDto">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ApplicationValuesDto" Property="applicationId" Title="Application ID" Visible="false"></RadzenGridColumn>
                                            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ApplicationValuesDto" Property="applicationName" Title="Application Name"></RadzenGridColumn>
                                            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ApplicationValuesDto" Property="commonName" Title="Common Name"></RadzenGridColumn>
                                            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ApplicationValuesDto" Property="typeOfApplication" Title="Type Of Application"></RadzenGridColumn>
                                          
                                            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ApplicationValuesDto" Title="Edit">
                                                <Template Context="d">
                                                    <button type="button" @onclick="(()=> NavigateToEditApplication(d.applicationId))">



                                                        <img src="../assets/img/imageresize.png" />

                                                    </button>
                                                </Template>
                                            </RadzenGridColumn>
```

Updated post

How to add `Radzen.Blazor.GridColumnVisibilityChooser` so i can control visibility of columns exist on radzen grid .

desired result
[image: column picker visability]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue related to display all column visibility on Ridzen Grid
I change

```
RidzenGrid
```

to

```
RidzenDataGrid
```

and add `AllowColumnPicking="true"`

and it display column visibility drop down

this already feature exist on `ridzendatagrid` name `allowcolumnpicking`

and it working success